# Cant select invidual rows of a view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

The view looks like this:

```
Create or Replace view MyView( Col1, Col2, Col3) as 
select count(OuterQ.Name), OuterQ.Year, Outer.Date 
      (select InnerQ.Name, InnerQ.Year, X.Date, 
         From X
            , ( select p.Id, p.Name, t.year from p,t where p.id = t.id) InnerQ 
        where X.field = 'YYY' 
          and X.value = t.value) OuterQ 
group by OuterQ.Date, OuterQ.Year
```

When I need one particular column value from the view for instance `select Col1 from MyView;` I get the error *"904 invalid identifier"*.

But when I run `select * from MyView`, the query runs fine.

Comment: We're gonna need more info than this. The error message means exactly what it says; Oracle is confused.  Put the entire SQL statement into your question.

Comment: Is one of the columns you're selecting in mixed case? You could be doing SELECT MYCOLUMN FROM MYTABLE when the column name is actually "MYCOLUMN" or similar.

Comment: No it doesnt have any mixed case

Comment: @Prash please run `select table_name, column_name from all_tab_columns where upper(table_name) = upper('MYVIEW') and upper(column_name) = upper('COL1')` and add the output to your answer. also show the error happening from a sql*plus prompt if possible to rule out any oddities with the client you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors:

```
-- first off , remove ( Col1, Col2, Col3) 
Create or Replace view MyView( Col1, Col2, Col3) as

select count(OuterQ.Name), OuterQ.Year, Outer.Date

-- you should have FROM clause here or   
(select InnerQ.Name, InnerQ.Year, X.Date,

From X, (select p.Id, p.Name, t.year from p,t where p.id = t.id) InnerQ

where X.field = 'YYY' and X.value = t.value) OuterQ

 -- FROM Clause here of outer query    
group by OuterQ.Date, OuterQ.Year
```